# "Задачка" на составление SQL-запроса

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос:

```sql
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`,'%d.%m.%Y') AS `date`
FROM testresults
WHERE
 `timestamp` > '2011-08-01' AND
 `timestamp` NOT LIKE ('2011-08-04%') AND
 `publish` = '1'
ORDER BY
 SUBSTRING(`timestamp`, 1, 10) DESC,
 `green` DESC,
 `red` ASC,
 `white` ASC,
 `timestamp` DESC
```

Запрос вытаскивает записи результатов тестов за текущий месяц и сортирует их по дням таким образом, чтобы тесты с лучшими результатами "внутри" дня шли первыми.
Но мне, на самом деле, нужно выбрать только первую строчку "внутри" каждого дня, т.е. только одну строчку с самым лучшим результатом за каждый день текущего месяца.
Можно ли это сделать в данном запросе? И если можно, то каким образом нужно модифицировать запрос?

**upd:** Результат теста лежит в трех колонках: `green` (количество правильных ответов), `red` (количество неправильных) и `white` (количество вопросов без ответа). Если количество `green`, `red` и `white` у двух тестов одинаковое, то лучшим из них (в этот день) считается тот, который сделан позже по времени (поле `timestamp`, формат этого поля `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`). В `ORDER BY` видно как сортируются результаты.

Если бы поле в котором лежит результат было бы одно, то можно было бы сделать `MAX()` по этому полю, сгруппировав записи по дням. Но здесь фактически четыре поля определяющих лучший результат и я не вижу варианта как можно по ним сделать `МАX()` или что-то подобное ...

т.е. по сути надо сделать что-то типа "`LIMIT 1 внутри каждого дня`" ... вот только как и можно ли это сделать вообще?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению, в mysql нет аналитических функций, поэтому придёться немного поизвращаться.
Примерно так.

```
select * 
from   testresults t, 
       (select   max(a.id) as id 
        from     testresults a, 
                 (select   max(result) res, 
                           date(day)   d 
                  from     testresults 
                  group by date(day)) b 
        where    a.result = b.res 
                 and date(a.day) = b.d 
        group by a.result, 
                 date(a.day)) x 
where  t.id = x.id;
```

Хороший, кстати, вопрос) Тут таких мало.

Comment: мм.. господа их хэшкода. Я ещё понимаю, когда вы правите грамматику. Но зачем же форматирование запроса править? Я предпочитаю другой стиль, у нас тут вроде бы кодинг стандарта нет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ :) Я так и думал, что не получится это сделать одним "относительно простым" запросом, но сомневался.

Comment: Мы не настаиваем. Если Вы не согласны с правками, Вы всегда можете откатить их обратно.

Comment: Не понял, этот запрос не решает поставленную задачу.

Comment: Ну да, это упрощённая версия, но, я думаю, автор может сам модифицировать запрос под свои нужды. Если решать за других всё до конца, то за что они зарплату получать будут? :)

Comment: Я так понял, что у автора проблема именно с тем, что результат по нескольким полям и ему именно в эту сторону нужен волшебный пендель. Возможно, я ошибся.

Comment: ну, в данном случае зарплаты нет - это некоммерческий проект :) Запрос получается слишком сложным (извращенным), т.е. использовать его непрактично (запрос сложен для понимания, что усложняет поддержку этого кода в будущем, например, новым разработчиком). Оставил старый запрос + цикл на php, который оставляет в полученном наборе записей только первую запись из каждого дня. На мой взгляд, это решение является оптимальным для данного случая. Жаль конечно, что не получилось сделать все это только одним запросом :)

Comment: Хорошим решением будет написать пользовательскую функцию, которая вычисляет значение для сортировки, тогда запрос будет выглядеть вполне читаемо

Answer (score 3):

Сгруппировать по дням и выбрать MAX(). Напишите структуру таблицы - в какой колонке лежит результат решительно непонятно.

Теперь ясно. Предложение такое: раз результат не из одного поля, то максимум можно собирать по искусственно построенному выражению. Допустим, в тесте не может быть больше 100 вопросов. Тогда максимум ищем по выражению

```sql
MAX( ((green*100) + white) * (60*60*24) -
   ((HOUR(timestamp)*60+MINUTE(timestamp))*60+SECOND(timestamp)) )
```

**Исправлено**. Конечно же не на 24 надо умножать а на 60, потому как в часу 60 минут

**Дополнено**.

```sql
SELECT t.* FROM testresults t 
JOIN (SELECT DAY(timestamp) AS md, MAX( ((green*100) + white) * (60*60*24)- ((HOUR(timestamp)*60+MINUTE(timestamp))*60+SECOND(timestamp)) ) AS mr 
    FROM testresults 
    WHERE ... GROUP BY DAY(timestamp)) tm 
    ON tm.md = DAY(timestamp) AND tm.mr = ((green*100) + white) * (60*60*24)- ((HOUR(timestamp)*60+MINUTE(timestamp))*60+SECOND(timestamp))
ORDER BY DAY(timestamp)
```

Comment: думал об таком (комплексное выражение для МАХ()) варианте, но я не догадался как в этой "формуле" учитывать время теста. Теперь вижу как можно это сделать. Вообще-то в тестах может быть разное количество вопросов, но может и получится - надо подумать. Спасибо за предложение :)

Comment: требуется верхняя граница числа вопросов не по каждому тесту, а по всем. Помнится мне, полный MMPI содержит около 600 вопросов, поэтому можно смело взять границу 1000

Comment: нет, не получается так. можно сделать такой запрос:
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`,'%d.%m.%Y') AS `date`,
MAX(`green` * 10000000 - `red` * 1000000 - `white` * 100000 + HOUR(`timestamp`)* 3600 + MINUTE(`timestamp`) * 60 + SECOND(`timestamp`))
FROM `testresults`
WHERE
 `timestamp` > '2011-08-01' AND
 `timestamp` NOT LIKE ('2011-08-04%') AND
 `publish` = '1'
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(`timestamp`, 1, 10)
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(`timestamp`, 1, 10) DESC
он все правильно сортирует, но сами записи-то мы получить не можем, а только "итоги по группе", а это не то ...

Comment: ну вон же @AndrewFrolov привел запрос, который можно взять за образец. сейчас набросаю и приведу в ответе

Answer (score 2):

А нет ли у Вас возможности добавить в таблицу еще одно поле, которое будет представлять общую оценку и вычисляться и вноситься в базу одновременно с конкретными результатами (правильно/не правильно/нет ответа).

Можно предложить такую функцию:
пусть red+green+white - число вопросов в тесте.
Считаем оценку:

```
note = (green - red)/(red + green + white) + 1
```

(если не подходит, можете составить свою функцию, возможно, лучше соответствующую вашей сортировке Ж) )

оценка будет в области 0...1...2, где 0 означает "все неправильно", 1  - "ни одного отвеченного либо число правильных и неправильных одинаково", 2 - "все правильно". (единицу добавили чтобы оценка всегда была неотрицательна, см. ниже)

Для включения времени в оценку можно воспользоваться побитовым OR скомпоновав например, 64-битное целое таким образом, чтобы в старших разрядах (можно не во всех, мне кажется, достаточно, например 11 бит - значения от 0 до 2048 - помножим note на 1000 и получим нужное значение с сохранением точности 0.1%), сохранять note, а в младших - timestamp.... - таким образом, при сравнении главную роль будет играть оценка, а при одинаковых оценках - величина timestamp...

> Если бы поле в котором лежит результат было бы одно, то можно было бы сделать MAX() по этому полю, сгруппировав записи по дням. Но здесь фактически четыре поля определяющих лучший результат и я не вижу варианта как можно по ним сделать МАX() или что-то подобное ...

Вот у Вас получится "одно поле". кстати Вы можете и не создавать это поле, а вычислять его значение в условии ORDER BY (...), но при большом количестве тестов - это дооолго...

Answer (score 2):

Лучший результат - это какая-то функция от `green, red, white,` так и сделайте функцию, которая будет подсчитывать это значение, напр.:

```
points = green * n * n - red * n  - white + time
```

где n - максимально допустимое количество вопросов, а time - фунция от времени. Добавите поле в таблицу и считайте значение при вставке. Тогда все сводится к банальной выборке:

```sql
SELECT t.id, 
       t.green,
       t.white,
       trunc (t.test_date) as test_date
  FROM result_table t,
       ( 
         SELECT trunc(test_date) as test_date, 
                max (points) as points
           FROM result_table
          WHERE green = green -- тут добавить нужный вам критерий             
          group by trunc(test_date) 
       ) x
 WHERE t.points = x.points
```

**p.s. название таблицы, полей и использование oracle функции trunc заменить на нужные вам**

Может я не все правильно понял, вы храните timestamp в строке? Еще и не в том формате, в которым выводите, может это действительно необходимо, но при каждом запросе вызываете две функции необязательно:

```sql
DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`,'%d.%m.%Y') AS `date`
SUBSTRING(`timestamp`, 1, 10) DESC
```

второе нам уже не надо из-за points, а первое можно сделать дополнительным полем - display_date, и тоже забивать значение при вставке. Итого таблица будет иметь вид:

```sql
id, points, green, red, white, display_date, timestamp (+ другие ваши столбики)
```

В случае, если таблица `testresults` слишком большая, то можно разбить ее на две:

```
testresults_for_search:  id, points, date (для фильтрации по дате)   
testresults: id, green, red, white, display_date, timestamp (ваш стамп в строке)
```

Предполагается, что первая будет сканироватся полностью, а вторая по индексу - id.